# Unable to open connection with websocket on tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have the following ServerEndpoint which is nothing more than a test:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/echo")
public class EchoService {

 /**
 * @OnOpen allows us to intercept the creation of a new session.
 * The session class allows us to send data to the user.
 * In the method onOpen, we'll let the user know that the handshake was 
 * successful.
 */
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session){
    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * When a user sends a message to the server, this method will intercept the message
 * and allow us to react to it. For now the message is read as a String.
 */
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
    System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);
    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * The user closes the connection.
 * 
 * Note: you can't send messages to the client from this method
 */
@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session){
    System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
}

}
```

now I am trying to connect to it using the [Simple Websocket Client Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo), but it never get to connect.

I thinking it may be related to the fact that I am using Tomcat 8 as servlet container. I added this dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that I setted it as provided since tomcat 8 comes with websocket api..
I am wondering if I should add something to my web.xml, but cant find anything related..

The URI I am trying to connect is ws://localhost:8080/ecommerce-view/echo since my project war is named ecommerce-view

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@ServerEndpoint("/echo")`. So, remove `value=`

Comment: Hmm..I've tried to duplicate your project with the same EchoService, same dependency and the same chrome plugin and everything is working fine. So, code wise it seems fine. Is your EchoService in the src/main/java directory? Anything wierd in tomcat logs?

Comment: Yes and no, nothing logged, maybe my problem is something on web.xml, I will update the question tomorrow with the content of the that file